# A problem on measure restriction

Tags: measure-theory

Definition of measurable space:
An ordered pair $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ is a **measurable space** if $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$.

Definition of measure:
Let $(\Omega, F)$ be a measurable space, $μ$ is an non-negative function defined on $\mathcal{F}$ (that is $\mu: \mathcal{F} \to [0, +\infty]$). If $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$ and $\mu$ is countably additive (that is $A_n \in \mathcal{F}$, $n \geqslant 1$, $A_n \cap A_m = \emptyset$, $n \neq m \Rightarrow \mu(\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(A_n)$) then $\mu$ is a **measure** on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$.

Definition of measure space:
Let μ is a measure on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ then $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ is a **measure space**.

My problem is 
suppose $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ is a finite measure space($\mu(\Omega) < + \infty$), $\Omega_0 \subset \Omega$ and $\mu^*(\Omega_0) = \mu(\Omega)$.

Then **show $\mu^*(A \cap \Omega_0) = \mu(A)$ for $\forall A \in \mathcal{F}$.**

Does anyone have any idea how to prove it?

Update:

I'm so sorry. I put a word "let" in front of $\mu^*(\Omega_0) = \mu(Ω)$. The original problem have no word "let" there. I've deleted it.

I've searched the $μ^∗$ before this problem and the only place at which $μ^∗$ first came out is $μ^∗ (A) = \inf \{ \sum _{n=1}^ {\infty}\mu(A_n) | A_n \in \mathcal{F}, A \subset \cup _{n=1}^ {\infty} A_n \}$, $A ⊂ \Omega$. The solutions give me a hint that show $\Omega_0 ∩ F$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. I'm not sure what's the relationship between $\sigma$-algebra $\Omega_0 ∩ F$ and the problem I need to prove.

Comment: Is $\mu^*$ another measure ? an outer measure ?

Comment: You have misstated what it is you need to prove. Getting the problem straight is the first step...

Comment: @Bearandbunny The problem with your post was not that you didn't highlight what you needed to prove! You have stated the problem incorrectly. Either it's wrong in the book or you copied it wrong. Look very carefully for something you left out. HINT: It's _impossible_ to prove _anything_ about $\mu^*(A\cap\Omega_0)$ because you have given us no hint what that notation even _means_.

Comment: This still makes no sense to me. I will have to agree with @DavidC.Ullrich , you have somehow got something wrong. It is no clear what is $\mu^*$: how you can say "let $\mu^*(\Omega_0)=\mu(\Omega)$" (note here that $\mu(\Omega) = c \in \mathbb{R}^+$ with $c< \infty$, so your hypothesis is telling us nothing) and then ask to prove $\mu^*(A\cap \Omega_0)=\mu(A)$....? Please check your question

Comment: @Bearandbunny For future reference: You say that you _noticed_ that $\mu^*(A\cup\Omega_0)$ was undefined? Then you should have started there, trying to find out what the definition was! You need to know what the notation means _before_ trying to prove anything...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: $μ^∗ (A) = inf$ {$\sum _{n=1}^ {\infty}μ(A_n) | A_n ∈ F, A ⊂ \cup _{n=1}^ {\infty} A_n$}, $A ⊂ Ω$

Comment: That´s the outer measure generated by the measure $\mu$. The interesting thing here is that $\mu^*: \mathcal{P}(\Omega) \to \mathbb{R}^+$ meanwhile  $\mu: F \to \mathbb{R}^+$, hence $\mu^*$ is not restricted to sets belonging to the $\sigma$-algebra

Comment: The length of the comment chain raised an automatic flag, so I trimmed it in response - hopefully the end result is still coherent. If you need to revisit a deleted comment flag a moderator to the scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a correct version of the standard definition of an outer measure $\mu^*$ given a measure $\mu$, and assuming that we're supposed to simply assuume that $\Omega_0\subset\Omega$ satisfies $\mu^*(\Omega_0)=\mu(\Omega)$ (that word "let" threw me off):

Suppose $A\in F$. If we let $A_1=A$ and $A_n=\emptyset$ for $n>1$ then $A_n\in F$ and $A\cap\Omega_0\subset\bigcup A_n$, so $$\mu^*(A\cap\Omega_0)\le\sum\mu(A_n)=\mu(A).$$Now, writing $A^c$ for $\Omega\setminus A$, the same argument shows that $$\mu^*(A^c\cap\Omega_0)\le\mu(A^c),$$hence $$\mu^*(A\cap\Omega_0)+\mu^*(A^c\cap\Omega_0)\le\mu(A)+\mu(A^c)=\mu(\Omega).$$ But $\mu^*$ is subadditive, hence $$\mu(\Omega)=\mu^*(\Omega_0)\le\mu^*(A\cap\Omega_0)+\mu^*(A^c\cap\Omega_0)=\mu(\Omega).$$So we must have equality throughout.

Exercise: Determine exactly where we used the fact that $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$.

Exercise: Show that the result is false without the assumption that $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$.

The two exercises are not the same, btw.

(Exercise: If $x'\le x$, $y'\le y$ and $x'+y'\ge x+y$ then $x=x'$ and $y=y'$.)

Comment: Nah, downright sneaky of me to be typing up the answer while I kept you busy wondering what I was talking about in those comments... heh, sorry.

Comment: I've checked the original problem. There is no word"let" and just $μ^∗ (Ω_0) = μ(Ω)$. I will correct it. Sorry about that.

Comment: How did you have $\sum μ(A_n) = μ(A)$?

Comment: Are the $A_n$ you use those {$A_n$} achieve $inf$ of $μ^*$?

Comment: @Bearandbunny In retrospect it may look like we were just being mean, picking on you guys over details. But it's the honest truth that the word "let" threw me way off. Hard to say exactly why. "Let" sort of introduces something new - a new variable, a new definition, something. You'd already supposed $\Omega_0\subset\Omega$ a millisecond earlier, so when I see "let $\mu^*(\Omega_0)=\mu(\Omega)$ that had to be the definition of $\mu^*$ or something. Which made no sense...

Comment: $\mu(A_1)=\mu(A)$. For $n>1$, $\mu(A_n)=\mu(\emptyset)=0$. And $\mu(A)+0+0+0+...=\mu(A)$.
Those $A_n$ do achieve the infimum I believe, but that doesn't matter at that point. The outer measure is the inf of all such sums, so the outer measure is less than or equal to any one such sum.

Comment: Got it. I appreciate your kindness and patience.

Comment: Right - we'll see what you say when you get the bill...